# Pressing "W" turned my cursor into a circle

Tags: 3d-view, interface, edit-mode, selection-tools, shortcut

I was editing a curve for hair, and pressed <kbd>W</kbd> to bring the specials menu and *Subdivide* it, but instead everything but the curve I had active dissapeared, and my cursor turned into a circle like the one from the circle select mode.

I'm guessing they changed the specials menu and I'm inside some unknown to me function, but I'm not sure how to turn everything back to normal.

[image]

Comment: Press W a few more times. The cursor will filter through until it gets back to where you want it.

Answer (score 10):

In the new default *Left Click Select* keymap:

- right click (<kbd>RMB</kbd>) is what opens the menu for context-based special actions (*Subdivide, Remove Doubles*, etc),

  while instead
- <kbd>W</kbd> cycles through the *Selection* tools from the Tools shelf

  [image]

So now you've got *Subdivide* on <kbd>RMB</kbd>, and you can get your pointer back by hitting <kbd>W</kbd> 3 times.

If you want to go back to Blender 2.79 *Right Click Select* keymap, you'll find this option in *Edit > Preferences > Input > Select with*.

---

The reason why everything else has disappeared is that you are in Local view (read that little `(Local)` in the Viewport's top left corner). I'm not sure how you entered this mode, and the <kbd>W</kbd> stuff is completely unrelated, but you can exit it using <kbd>/</kbd> or *View > Local View > Toggle Local View*